# Executing terminal commands in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to run the following in Jupyter notebook (with Python 2 if it makes a difference):

`!head xyz.txt`

and I get the following error:

> 'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Is there anything I need to import to be able to do this?

Comment: `head` is part of unix shell. You cannot use it on windows.

Comment: thank you cel, that clears it

Comment: The difference between different ways in which terminal commands can be executed in Jupyter notebooks is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512566/446855) to the question [cd vs !cd vs %cd in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512527/cd-vs-cd-vs-cd-in-ipython).

Answer (score 69):

Might be useful for others.
Use ! followed by terminal command you want to execute. To run a shell command. E.g.,

`! pip install some_package`

to install the some_package.

Comment: I might add that for the equivalent `conda install` command, add `-y` or `--yes` to prevent it from hanging while waiting for user  confirmation input. (E.g `conda install some_package -y`)

Comment: [Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-sc). -- (from the link) "*all expressions prefixed with ‘$’ get expanded. [...] If you want to access a true shell variable, an extra $ is necessary to prevent its expansion by IPython*"

Comment: I know it was meant to be illustrative; however,  that particular command is no longer a good choice to run in modern Jupyter. The modern magic commands for `pip install` and `conda install` have been added to insure that installations occur in the appropriate environment backing the notebook kernel. **Use of an exclamation point alone doesn't insure that and can cause issues.** See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install`.

Answer (score 55):

An easier way to invoke terminal using jupyter-notebooks is to use magic function `%%bash` and use the jupyter cell as a terminal:

```
%%bash
head xyz.txt
pip install keras
git add model.h5.dvc data.dvc metrics.json
git commit -m "Second model, trained with 2000 images"
```

Comment: this is what worked in the aws sagemaker notebooks for me

Answer (score 18):

For Windows it would be %%cmd.

Write it at the beginning of the cell like this :

```
%%cmd
where python
myprogram "blabla" -x -y -z
```

Comment: What is the difference between prefixing the command with "%%" or with "!" ?

Comment: @skan Everything well explained in those two paragraphs : [Shell assignment](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment). Double '%%' works for the whole cell while '%' or '!' are for one line only.

Answer (score 5):

You can start the cell with the magic `% bash` before the rest of your code. There is an example in [this blog post](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/lesser-known-ways-of-using-notebooks/), together with a list of some of the most useful magics.

Comment: I was able get it running with double percent:
%%bash

Answer (score 3):

I just want to mention a different approach.

```
import os

os.system("""
    your commands
""")
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run your command in linux shell because there is non such command in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Another option nowadays is [the Jupyter kernel for Bash](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved by running

```
!bash -c "head xyz.txt"
```