# What does the `-qq` mean as a pip install option?

Tags: python, pip

I saw this on a jupyter notebook:

```
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
```

`!` [runs commands on shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529220/5986651). `U` stands for upgrade. What do the options `qq` mean? `q` stands for quiet.

**Why are there two q's**?

Looked up `pip install --help`.
Looked up [User guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages) to no avail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **option -q of pip** give less output.

The Option is additive. In other words, you can use it up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).

So:

- `-q`   means display only the messages with WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL log levels
- `-qq`  means display only the messages with ERROR,CRITICAL log levels
- `-qqq` means display only the messages with CRITICAL log level

Comment: Stupid question, but is it possible to display the INFO logs but suppress the WARNING logs?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 logging levels, so `-q` can be used up to 3 times to hide these message types:

1. Warning
2. Error
3. Critical

This type of option is called "additive," meaning you can apply it more than once to tune the app settings.

So you can use `-q` to suppress various levels of debug output:

```
-q:   hide WARNING messages
-qq:  hide WARNING and ERROR messages
-qqq: hide all messages
```

FYI the option `-v` is also additive  and can be used up to 3 times.

More information available at the [pip reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/)