# What does `pip install -qq <package>` do?

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I'm reading a code that uses  `pip install -qq <package>` to install python packages.

I know what is pip and what `pip install` does. But I don't know what is that `-qq` and when should I use it.
I googled it and searched it on SO but didn't find anything. Will be glad if you can help me understand this.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64277651/1993580).

Comment: `pip install --help`.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#quiet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip install -q is an option to --

Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).