# Cannot run internal or external commands in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to run shell commands in the Jupyter notebook but it doesn't work

```
!which python
```

It shows an error

```
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on windows based system:

```
!where python
```

Else:

```
%%bash
which python
```

References:

- https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-which-equivalent-cmd-powershell/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529220/15488129

Comment: I get this response Couldn't find program: 'bash'

Comment: @AhmedAlsonaffi I think you are trying to use unix commands on windows OS. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried the first code of the answer?

Comment: Yes, it works but it does show the result I want, it is a different command than which

Comment: Please then describe desired output :)

Comment: @AhmedAlsonaffi this answer is the answer to your question. If you have additional questions, you should ask a new question.

Comment: It's not the answer, I mean there are a lot of shell commands that do not run on Jupiter and shows error. How can I run them

Comment: @AhmedAlsonaffi but you are using Windows - why should UNIX commands to be available?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run python3 --version. I am assuming you are using Windows. Open your command line and run the command too. If you still get the same response, it means you did not add python to path while installing. Did you install using Anaconda?

If you want to add python to path, just simply follow this link. It's self-explanatory. Let me know in the comment section if you still have issues.

https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: I get the same response when 'i run the command in the cmd

Comment: This means you did not add python to your virtual environment. There are two ways out of this. Add the python path to your environment variable manually or reinstall python and click on add to path when the installation screen pops up