# Mounting google drive on google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I followed the steps given in this Medium tutorial on google colab and then tried to clone a git repository but I cannot see the repository anywhere in my drive.

The following image is the code snippet I used which is exactly the same as that from the Medium tutorial:
[image: The code snippet I used which is exactly the same as that from the Medium tutorial]

How can I add a path to my Google Drive in Google Colab?

Comment: Do we need to run these commands and perform authorization every time I use my notebook?

Answer (score 6):

To mount google drive on google Colab just use these commands:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It would need an authentication process. Do whatever it needs (open the link and copy the key)

Now you have mounted your google drive in `/content/drive/` directory in your google Colab machine.

To clone a git repository, first set your current directory as a path in `/content/drive/`, then just clone the git repository. Like below:

```
path_clone = "/content/drive/my_project"
%cd path_clone
!git clone <Git project URL address>
```

Now you would have the cloned Git project in `my_projects` folder in your Google Drive (which is also connected to your Google Colab runtime machine)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust ur path where you git clone.
try adding drive folder to path

```
import os
os.chdir("drive")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `cd drive` (without `!`) or `%cd drive`.

See [cd vs !cd vs %cd in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512527/cd-vs-cd-vs-cd-in-ipython).