# cannot access folder in Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

last day I used this command

import os

os.listdir('drive')

and get access

but today when i used the same command it generates error

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 import os
----> 2 os.listdir('drive')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive'

Answer (score 0):

Your VM has likely been reset. (VMs are reset once inactive for some time.)

You'll need to re-execute the cells used to mount Drive. I'm guessing you've used a recipe like the one described here:

[Mounting google drive on google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168315/mounting-google-drive-on-google-colab)